# Scala create a function to run on existing type

Tags: scala

For simplicities sake I removed all the types from what I intend to do and using a simple list here. Imagine I have a function which takes two parameters: a collection and a function and uses this to produce a new collection.

I know! this looks like reinventing map but the actual use case is a lot more different and complex. What I tried so far is something like:

```
trait SomeHelper {
  class CoolFunction( right: String => Boolean ) extends Function1[List[String], List[Any]] {
    inst =>
    override def apply( left: List[ String ] ): List[ Any ] = {
      left match {
        case a: List[String] => a.filter( right )
        case _ => List()
      }
    }
  }

  def coolFunction( right: String => Boolean ) = new CoolFunction( right )
}

object SomeHelper extends SomeHelper

import SomeHelper._

val myList = List("apple", "orange", "banana")

myList coolFunction {
  a => a == "orange"
}
```

produces me a "value coolFunction is not a member of List[String]"

feels like I am so close but can't figure it out

Comment: Why aren't you using `List.filter` instead of creating your own function type? It seems like you want to apply a predicate to a collection.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov again, I simplified the logic, I know this example looks like a re-implementation of map/filter it actually is not.

Comment: Then perhaps try to walk us towards what you're actually trying to do? This isn't making too much sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use an implicit class. They allow to add a method onto existing types.

```
implicit class MyListHelper(list: List[String]) {

  def doStuff(function: String => Any): List[Any] = {
    list.map(function)
  }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
import MyListHelper

val list = List("a", "b", "c")
val result = list.doStuff(s => s + s) // List("aa", "bb", "cc")
```

Comment: yes, this was what I used to do. My approach above allows me to create the CoolFunction as abstract and dictate my users to create an apply function with the generics conditions supplied by myself.  Do you know if I can do something similar for implicits? worst case scenario I will have two lambdas in `doStuff` definition which will then compose inside doStuff func1(funct2)